Aristotle's Golden Balance - bad for the economy?

Matt Haig in this quote: “Happiness is not good for the economy. We
are encouraged, continually, to be a little bit dissatisfied with
ourselves. …To be calm becomes a kind of revolutionary act. To be
happy with your own non-upgraded existence. To be comfortable with our
messy, human selves would not be good for business.”


Is this how our brain, ‘nature,’ works — always striving for upgrades
because we are designed to be insecure about how we authentically are?
If yes, is it really a good thing that we are wired or evolved this
way? Or is it caused by society, often referred to as ‘nurture’,
through its political systems that are usually constructed for
economic growth?
https://theithacan.org/49254/uncategorized/figure-of-soul-happiness-is-not-good-for-the-economy/

To follow this logic, political figures that stir things up (Hitlers, Trumps) are bad for balanced and happy individual lives but good for the economy and progress?
There is a metaphysical aspect to this question. What is more important for the Creator, human balanced happiness or 'unhappy' energy and progress?

My definition of addiction: too much is never enough. Econometrics can measure primarily only populations of people, goods, and the monetary value of services based on income or expenditure. The economy is driven forward by spending decisions of the government and private agents who deficit spend (go into debt) to provide public goods and services or private goods and services. If decisions to spend money go down GDP goes down. Past debts are commitments to make future nominal payments. When spending is down, income is down, and more debts default. Spending can be a tool for Hitler or Trump.

Obama stirred up a lot of hatred for white people and men. Why didn't you compare him to Hitler?

"Middle Class Syndrome" - when people are settled and happy they are less likely to go through hardships of starting something new.

@DavidGudeman - Obama was too good for America, Trump is too bad. Looking for a balance.

"Not everything that counts can be counted. And not everything that can be counted counts." Didn't the Buddha say something about being satisfied, long ago? Is it still just as true now?

Obama has a lot more in common with Hitler than Trump.

I wonder how Hitler was good for economy and progress...

@user58697 - just look at US and EU

Philosophy as a science has the chance to explain and influence the world's economy, politics and education.
Is it not more important than a shadow in a cave?

If people overcome negative egoic tendencies, then the good results will follow. It isn't Philosophy that is needed, it's Psychology. A movement isn't needed, but each person has to undertake self-study personally. Meditation is one helpful method, but more is needed. All of this was described thousands of years ago, it is not news.
